# How can I test if my /tmp "works"?

Tags: filesystems, osx, tmp

I had to delete some files and whatever, long story, I ran `sudo rm -rf /tmp/`.

Now, on mac (might be universal, I'm not sure) it is a symlink to `/private/tmp`/. But my `/tmp/` folder has a thumbnail which looks like a broken symlink in Finder (graphical).

But cding to `tmp` works. How can I see if the folder was recreated sucessfully?

```
$ stat -x /tmp/
File: "/tmp/"
Size: 238          FileType: Directory
Mode: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)         Uid: (    0/    root)  Gid: (    0/   wheel)
Device: 1,4   Inode: 68494519    Links: 7
Access: Wed Feb 18 14:35:10 2015
Modify: Wed Feb 18 14:31:16 2015
Change: Wed Feb 18 14:31:16 2015
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with OSX but it should be recreated when you reboot. As long as the `/tmp` mount point (folder) exists, I am guessing that everything will look normal after rebooting.

Comment: @tedon Good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, since you pretty much answer your question yourself... On Mac OS X `/tmp` is a symlink to `/private/tmp`. Both are owned by `root:wheel`; `/tmp` has mode `0755`, `/private/tmp` has mode `1777`. There is no `tmpfs`-style filesystem involved.

As [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) says, if the Finder gets confused, restarting it (or rebooting) should fix things. But even without that, as long as `/tmp` exists as described above, the system should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

`/tmp` is a `Virtual File System` such as `sysfs`. Before any action you have to `umount /tmp/`, then remove it. However almost all Unix OSes need it, so I don't know why you want to remove `/tmp`.

**UPDATE:**

In  GNU\Linux OS:
`/tmp` didn't mount and if you grep in mount:

```
root@debian:~# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=751838,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1206328k,mode=755)
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=21,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=603164k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

But some Unixes uses /tmp as `tmpfs`.

You can do it :

```
mount |grep -i tmp
```

Comment: It was an accident.

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: "/tmp is a Virtual File System" - don't you meant `tmpfs`?